# How to push messages to AMQP consumer Artemis

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

Is it possible for Artemis to push messages to a REST API/consumer, rather the consumer pulling from it. I can implement a Listener on the consumer side, but I am trying to see if Artemis can push messages to consumers.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What messaging API/protocol is your consuming using? Most clients (e.g. AMQP, JMS, STOMP, MQTT) support registering a listener to which the broker will push messages.

Comment: I can implement my consumer by registering a listener using JMS. Was looking for alternate options.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to see if Artemis can push messages to consumers"? If you register a listener with the broker then it will push messages to it. Are you looking to avoid registering a listener? If so, why? Are you, for example, wanting to statically configure a consumer in `broker.xml`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like to know if I can configure consumers in broker.xml. I saw from the documentation that you can configure another broker in broker.xml and artemis will push messages to it. Can I similarly configure a REST end point in broker.xml and Artemis post messages to that?

Comment: No, you cannot configure consumers in `broker.xml`. That's not really how client/server architectures work. Bridges exist to send messages between *servers*. If a client wants the server to push a message to it then most protocols support "listener" functionality to enable such behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's possible, the JMS provider is a server and always waits for consumer connections. Then, it pushes messages to consumer's buffer as soon as it is ready and there are available messages. Anyway, depending on your application's technology, you may want to leverage the [Artemis REST interface](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/rest.html) to implement your consumer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, understand REST is one way to do this, I was trying to see if there is any configuration in artemis, where it can push to a consumer, It seems to be capable of pushing messages to another queue/topic.

Comment: Messages are always pushed to connected consumers. You can disable the consumer's buffer by setting `consumerWindowSize=0` on the connection's URL. In that case, messages are sent one by one. You can send to another queue using a bridge, but you need to have a JMS broker on the other side.

Comment: FWIW, I would avoid using the Artemis REST interface. In situations where REST is attractive STOMP is almost always a better choice. Any client using the Artemis REST interface will not be portable.